# In a shiny input function, can I set the initial value to be missing, rather than NULL?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm building a shiny app that interacts with a library I've built. Functions in that library have a bunch of optional arguments. The functions are written so that they can easily handle cases where `missing(argument) == TRUE`.

Shiny's input functions allow one to set the default value of the input if the user doesn't specify it themselves. **Is it possible to set the default value to be missing (i.e., nonexistent)?**

For example, this is how to set the default value to `NULL`, but that isn't what I want.

```
textInput("argument", label = "Set this optional argument",
          value = NULL)
```

**EDIT:**
In all likelihood, I should just change my functions to have a default value of `NULL`, rather than using the `missing` function from base to set defaults. Nonetheless, I'm still curious if it's possible to set a default value to be nonexistent.

Comment: So, the issue is that if `input$argument` has a value, you call some function `f(value=input$argument)`, but if nothing is selected, you call `f()` with `value` receiving the default value? This is a more general problem with R optional values and I've seen a few different ways around it, none of which is fully satisfactory:

Comment: This provides one option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765153/make-conditional-argument-call-to-function-with-possibly-empty-argument?noredirect=1&lq=1
While this suggests using `missing`, rather than the default method for optional arguments, in your function which would give you more flexibility: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370249/correct-way-to-specifiy-optional-arguments-in-r-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @divibisan that's basically it, I've written my functions so that `if(missing(argument))`, then I set the default value to some function-specific value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to use `do.call` with a parameter list in which you put all your args for your function. Then you filter this list to filter out "missing" values. For a parameter in a `textInput` this could be an empty string (`. == ""`) or any other criterion upon which you decide that this is a "missing" input.

```
f <- function(y, x) if (missing(x)) "is missing" else "present"

ui <- fluidPage(textInput("ti", "Set Arg:"), 
                verbatimTextOutput("out"))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$out <- renderPrint({
     ## put all your potential args (optional and non optional) in a list 
     args <- list(y = 1, x = input$ti)
     ## Filter out NULL values
     ## define Filter fun which returns TRUE if you consider the value valid
     is_valid <- function(.) !is.null(.) && . != ""
     ## Filter out non valid args
     args <- Filter(is_valid, args)
     ## Use do.call to run your fun (non valid args are not set)
     list(inp = input$ti,
          out = do.call(f, args))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```